# Split excel file in set of files

Tags: excel

I have a file in Excel with only in the first column on about 200 rows. Is it possible to save the content of each row in 200 single files in word with different names?

At the moment I have a macro to split the data in 200 excel files but I have to save them manually.

```
Sub Macro1() 
    ' ' Macro1 Macro 
    ' ' Scelta rapida da tastiera: CTRL+t ' 
    Selection.Cut 
    Workbooks.Add 
    ActiveSheet.Paste 
    Windows("Articoli da considerare - Ecosys.xlsx").Activate 
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp 
End Sub
```

---

Thanks for your answer, but in this way I got one single file, whilst I need a file per each cell from the Excel dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mail Merge in word document. This does not require any macro code if you want to simply save each file.

In case you need help starting on this, here is a [link](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3).